# Return all objects in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm missing something super obvious here so please excuse my ignorance :(

I have a set of 5 checkboxes and would like to print out steps based on what checkbox was chosen. I'll need this for a bigger output so I'm storing the selection in it's own variable like so:

```
        $checkBox.find('input:checked').each(function() {
        $rec = $(this).val() + "\n";
        console.log($rec);

    });
```

Everything returns fine when I select all 5 checkboxes and check in console:

[console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAZqb.png)

However, I want to use the output stored in $rec to use later so I did this to see what it will look like:

```
        $checkBox.find('input:checked').each(function() {

        $rec = $(this).val() + "\n";
        console.log($rec);

    }); 

// call rec into text input
        $textOutput.val($textOutput.val() + $rec + "\n");
        console.log($rec);
```

But for some reason, only the "Do Step 5" is returned when calling $rec again

[second console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UN1kt.png)

Since I'm already storing output of the 5 checkboxes in $rec why can't I access all again rather than just the last object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to make $rec an array[]

and push your values into it. Something like

```
$rec.push($(this).val() + "\n");
```

Comment: this helped! thanks! declared $rec as an empty array at the top of the function.

Answer (score 0):

> But for some reason, only the "Do Step 5" is returned when calling $rec again

You're assigning the value to `$rec` each time, so when you `console.log()` in each iteration, you get the current value. But when you `console.log()` after the each is finished, you only get the last value that was assigned to the variable. This is because when you assign a variable, you "overwrite" the existing value (technically you point the variable at a different value), either way, any reference to the previous value is lost.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation! was great to know why it was happening.